# how to fix (or reinstal) UEFI boot patition on GPT disk?

Tags: debian, boot, grub, uefi

Debian 11 new install on new hard disk, UEFI mode and GPT partitioned disk. The problem is, when boot system, the error is shown:

*"Internal hard disk drive not found. To resolve this issue, try to reset the drive. No bootable devices -- strike F1 to retry boot, F2 to enter setup menu, F5 to enter PSA."*

Installation was from Live USB, before this, I created partitions use GParted Live. I think possibly issue was when I created first (boot) partition, first I've set Label name 'efi', then tried to rename it to '/boot/efi': and GParted immediately hung and stop responds, so I had manually power-Off to force PC shut down. Possibly two slashes '/' in label name could cause an issue, but I'm not sure.

```
$ efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 000C
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0004,0003,0009,000A,000C
Boot0000* Debian    HD(1,GPT,c906677e-c2c2-42b5-b818-f0b19c046e95,0x800,0xfa000)/File(\EFI\Debian\shimx64.efi)
Boot0003* UEFI OS   HD(2,MBR,0xfcba9dae,0x14000,0x1388000)/File(\EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.EFI)
Boot0004* UEFI OS   HD(2,MBR,0xb45e11b8,0xaf800,0x600000)/File(\EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.EFI)
Boot0009* Onboard NIC(IPV4) PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x3)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(20474749bc75,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.00.0.0.0,0,0)..BO
Boot000A* Onboard NIC(IPV6) PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x3)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(20474749bc75,0)/IPv6([::]:<->[::]:,0,0)..BO
Boot000C* UEFI:  USB DISK 2.0 PMAP  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1d,0x0)/USB(1,0)/USB(3,0)/HD(1,MBR,0xcd9a6b9,0x5d4,0x146a)..BO
```

EDIT: blkid & fdisk output

```
$ sudo blkid
/dev/sdb1: BLOCK_SIZE="2048" UUID="2021-10-09-12-36-57-00" LABEL="d-live nf 11.1.0 xf amd64" TYPE="iso9660" PTUUID="0cd9a6b9" PTTYPE="dos" PARTUUID="0cd9a6b9-01"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="BOOT" UUID="2F1D-01E6" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="c906677e-c2c2-42b5-b818-f0b19c046e95"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="swap" UUID="1274a782-676a-41b0-8509-92f73bd675c3" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="4a555697-e713-400d-ae9e-613d028c7893"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="root" UUID="13503165-9c5f-498d-ab5f-0c13f11cbaa6" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="5484dedd-6adf-45af-b7b0-ba105d14528b"
/dev/sda4: LABEL="home" UUID="93c98828-5fb8-4c0e-b6bf-de8d13a9d22e" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="ae15bbdb-4e29-4dfa-aa99-b39e5377a098"
/dev/sdb2: SEC_TYPE="msdos" UUID="DEB0-0001" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="0cd9a6b9-02"

$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 465.76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: TOSHIBA HDWK105 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 0C3CF112-75DD-4197-9A0C-7C92036731C6

Device        Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1      2048   1026047   1024000   500M EFI System
/dev/sda2   1026048   9414655   8388608     4G Linux swap
/dev/sda3   9414656  61843455  52428800    25G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda4  61843456 976773119 914929664 436.3G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sdb: 7.22 GiB, 7747928064 bytes, 15132672 sectors
Disk model: USB DISK 2.0    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0cd9a6b9

Device     Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *        0 6240351 6240352    3G  0 Empty
/dev/sdb2        1492    6717    5226  2.6M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)


Disk /dev/loop0: 2.6 GiB, 2789027840 bytes, 5447320 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

In BIOS menu: [Debian (Drive not present)]

`smartctl` tool show the disk is Ok:

```
=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
```

/etc/fstab content:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a device; this may
# be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices that works even if
# disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system>             <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
UUID=2F1D-01E6                            /boot/efi      vfat    defaults,noatime 0 2
UUID=13503165-9c5f-498d-ab5f-0c13f11cbaa6 /              ext4    defaults,noatime 0 1
UUID=93c98828-5fb8-4c0e-b6bf-de8d13a9d22e /home          ext4    defaults,noatime 0 2
```

EDIT: parted error

```
root@debian:/# parted /dev/sda1
GNU Parted 3.4
Using /dev/sda1
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) p                                                                
Model: Unknown (unknown)
Disk /dev/sda1: 524MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  524MB  524MB  fat32

(parted) help toggle                                                      
  toggle [NUMBER [FLAG]]                   toggle the state of FLAG on partition
        NUMBER

    NUMBER is the partition number used by Linux.  On MS-DOS disk labels,
        the primary partitions number from 1 to 4, logical partitions from 5
        onwards.
        FLAG is one of: boot, root, swap, hidden, raid, lvm, lba, hp-service,
        palo, prep, msftres, bios_grub, atvrecv, diag, legacy_boot, msftdata,
        irst, esp, chromeos_kernel, bls_boot
(parted) toggle 1 esp                                                     
Error: No flags supported
(parted) toggle 1 bios_grub                                               
Error: No flags supported
(parted) quit
```

Comment: You can check drive status: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools if you have gnome-disks and in disks is smart status in icon. https://askubuntu.com/questions/983619/s-m-a-r-t-data-no-longer-available-in-ubuntu-16-04-disks-application And/or run chkdsk on all NTFS, fsck or e2fsck on all ext4 and dosfsck on all FAT32 partitions. https://askubuntu.com/questions/862724/grub2-failed-to-install/86587z682#865872 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789

Comment: `I created partitions use GParted Live` what partitions did you create? Clearly you've booted from a USB to run `efibootmgr -v` ... can you also add the output of `blkid` and maybe `fdsisk -l` - I'd ignore the theory that the drive has failed for now, since there's no indication that it has

Comment: I created efi, swap, root, home partitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `/dev/sda1` appears to be an EFI System Partition (ESP for short), it should have been configured to mount to `/boot/efi` by the Debian installer. The label is not really important, as the installer will normally configure `/etc/fstab` to mount it by filesystem UUID anyway.

The `/etc/fstab` line would in your case be:

```
UUID="2F1D-01E6"    /boot/efi    vfat   umask=0077,tz=UTC,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1 0 1
```

Since the bootloader was apparently successfully registered to the system NVRAM (as indicated by `efibootmgr -v`), it is possible that the disk is actually fine, but when trying to start up the system, the UEFI firmware might not give the disk enough time to spin up before attempting to read from it, causing a false "disk not detected" error condition.

If that's the problem, then you should check the BIOS settings for any option that would slow down the boot process by just a few seconds. Some BIOSes have a dedicated "boot delay" option for just this purpose. If there is no adjustable delay, you might have to try alternatives like disabling Fast Boot, enabling legacy USB support, etc... anything that could give the disk a few extra seconds to spin up.

Before converting to legacy mode, you might try setting the system to try booting from network before the "Debian" UEFI boot entry. That should definitely take enough time to allow the disk to complete spin-up. You may be able to accomplish this with the `efibootmgr` command:

```
efibootmgr --bootorder 0009,0000,0004,0003,000A,000C
```

Waiting for the network boot to fail might be irritating in regular use, but if the disk works with this configuration, it would confirm the problem is the slow-starting disk.

You said the disk is new, and in the comments you mentioned the system is an old Dell laptop. Is the disk an official spare part from Dell? If you just bought a generic 2.5" SATA HDD for it, you may have run into a hidden requirement that is fulfilled by the official Dell spare part disk but not necessarily by your chosen replacement disk: in order to work successfully as a system disk, the disk *needs to* be ready to receive commands by some `xxx` milliseconds after power-up, since that's when the system firmware checks for the disk.

If the `TOSHIBA HDWK105` you chose is significantly slower to start up than the  original disk, that problem might not be fixable by changing the boot method or any other available BIOS settings. If the disk is the same model as the original, remember that a large vendor like Dell might even get disks with custom firmware, optimized for a particular use case.

If the laptop is from the first half of 2010's, at that time UEFI was new and vendors like Dell might have still perceived the legacy boot mode as their primary target, and as a result, the UEFI boot mode might have received less testing. At that time, there was a lot of more or less buggy UEFI implementations. (The UEFI became mainstream in 2011, as Intel introduced the Sandy Bridge chipset that was designed to be used with UEFI rather than classic BIOS.)

If you want to try changing the boot mode from UEFI to legacy, you must boot from the live media and chroot into the HDD-based installation:

```
mount /dev/sda3 /mnt
mount -t proc none /mnt/proc
mount -t sysfs none /mnt/sys
mount -o rbind,rw /dev /mnt/dev
chroot /mnt /bin/bash
mount -a   # to mount the /home filesystem; not essential for this task
```

After the `chroot` command, your command-line session should be able to access the HDD-based installation essentially as if the system was booted from the HDD. So, you can use the normal package management tools to remove the `grub-efi-amd64*` packages and install `grub-pc*` packages in their stead:

```
apt remove grub-efi-amd64 grub-efi-amd64-bin grub-efi-amd64-signed
apt install grub-pc grub-pc-bin
```

You might also want to remove the packages related to the Secure Boot shim, as it's unnecessary in legacy boot mode:

```
apt remove shim-signed shim-unsigned shim-helpers-amd64-signed shim-signed-common
```

In order to provide a location for `grub-pc` to embed its core image, you could switch the partition type of `/dev/sda1` to `bios_grub`. It's a bit of a waste as `grub-pc` needs only 1 MB for its core image, but it would allow conversion back into UEFI mode in the future if necessary.

```
parted /dev/sda1
(parted) toggle 1 esp
(parted) toggle 1 bios_grub
(parted) quit
```

Then comment out the `/boot/efi` line in `/etc/fstab` and ensure `/boot/efi` is unmounted, as the beginning of that filesystem is going to be overwritten by the BIOS GRUB.

Now the disk is ready to have a BIOS-booting version of GRUB installed. Since the system may currently be booted in UEFI mode, you will need to specify the GRUB target architecture explicitly; by default, `grub-install` may attempt to install a bootloader that matches the system's current boot style.

```
grub-install --target=i386-pc /dev/sda
```

After this, the conversion should be complete: it's time to undo the chroot process:

```
umount /home # (if you ran "mount -a" after chrooting)
exit   # to pop out of the chrooted shell session
umount /mnt/dev
umount /mnt/sys
umount /mnt/proc
umount /mnt
```

Then it's time to reboot the system, go into BIOS, set the boot mode to Legacy, and set the HDD as the boot target.

Good luck! Working with name-brand laptops that have very minimal BIOS settings can be irritating, and systems with buggy/quirky early-version UEFI implementations can also be a headache. It seems you may have a system where these two facts combine.

Comment: the Boot menu already have all these options set: `Fast Boot: Disabled`, `Secure Boot: Disabled`, `Load Legacy Option Rom: Enabled`. The BIOS utility version is old (A11), and it have no built-in option to update BIOS. Perhaps that BIOS implenentation was developed without purpose to update it on dell laptops with ubuntu preinstalled.

Comment: So, de-facto this BIOS implementation fails to support UEFI boot. Afaik, Linux can boot fine from a GPT disk in BIOS mode. Then, how to properly convert UEFI mode to boot in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode?

Comment: The laptop isn't too old, Inspiron 3542. Original disk was also Toshiba, model `TOSHIBA_MQ01ABF050`. I attached it to USB port to show its original config, the [output](https://pastebin.com/raw/8LP55PL0) from Boot-info-script (/dev/sdc).

Comment: A quick googling seems to indicate Dell Inspiron 3542 was introduced in 2014 or so - or in other words, just about in the problematic time range. However, the newest BIOS update available for it is version A16, released in September 2020 with some Intel CPU security fixes. The original disk seems to have MBR partitioning and a BIOS-type GRUB, complicated by the presence of the Dell Recovery partition. The fact that even the instructions from updating the BIOS using boot from USB require switching to legacy boot mode suggest Dell did not trust the UEFI mode of this model very much.

Comment: I tried to slow down the boot by setting the system to boot from network before the "Debian" UEFI boot through the F12 one-time boot menu: this gave some delay when starting up, but didn't help, all the same, Debian Live is loaded from USB.  Tried also to update BIOS to A16, based on Dell update instructions - created bootable USB stick  with FreeDos, put bios.EXE inside FreeDos folder, and tried to boot from the USB key to the DOS prompt. But DOS prompt doesn't even shown, just blikning cursor.

Comment: From other sources, I find that  3442A16.exe is NOT even a DOS application, and will not run under FreeDOS. It may be a "Universal (Windows/MS DOS)" application,and it may run from a command line operating within a Windows environment, but it will not run in a pure DOS environment, despite what these installation instructions for it say.

Comment: I got error at this stage: `root@debian:/# apt install grub-pc grub-pc-bin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package grub-pc is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  grub2-common grub-common grub-efi-amd64

E: Package 'grub-pc' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package grub-pc-bin`.

Comment: 3442A16.exe is probably a Windows .EXE that will prompt you to insert an USB to which it will write an image of a bootable BIOS upgrade utility. It's probably possible to run that on a different computer to prepare a BIOS upgrade USB stick for your laptop. Alternatively, it might be one of various forms of self-extractors: you could try `unzip -l 3442A16.exe` or `unrar l 3442A16.exe` in Linux to see if those tools can access the contents.

Comment: Possibly, due to along with unnecessary Secure Boot shim packages, I also removed these that were marked as "were automatically installed and are no longer required":`efibootmgr`, `grub-common`, `grub2-common`, `mokutil`, `os-prober`.

Comment: The [`grub-pc`](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/grub-pc) and [`grub-pc-bin`](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/grub-pc-bin) definitely exist in the Debian 11 repository. Are you installing without a network connection, from a USB media that might have a reduced set of packages available? In that case, you might have to download the packages manually and install them with `dpkg -i package-name.deb`

Comment: No, network connection is working. I also did `sudo apt update` before install.

Comment: That's odd. The `apt` repository you're using might have a mirroring issue. Try another mirror or try again later?

Comment: There is an issue with flags: `(parted) toggle 1 esp`                                                    
`Error: No flags supported`
`(parted) toggle 1 bios_grub`                                               
`Error: No flags supported`.

Comment: Thanks for helpful info. I fixed the packages installation issue, that was due to DNS resolving fail, and therefore _apt update/install_ couldn't find the repository sources (file 'resolv.conf' was missed in /etc directory). Before final converting  boot mode from UEFI to legacy, I will try again to update the BIOS, so that to check the UEFI installation with the latest BIOS version.